# Open Graph api for feed returning inconsistent results

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Called the https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed url is randomly missing data.

Here's what I did

- Create a test user for my sandbox mode app with publish_stream and read_stream permissions
- Add a post to their wall via POST to graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed?access_token={token}
- Login as test user and confirm post was added to their news feed
- GET on graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed to view JSON data

So when I hit the feed, sometimes the successfully created Feed Post is in the JSON, and sometimes it's not.  Continually hitting that API endpoint (i.e. hitting refresh over and over in my browser) will have the data pop in and out in no discernable pattern.

I have no idea what I could be doing wrong, or if it's just Facebook for that matter.  What could be the problem?

Comment: I doubt this should happen. You might have found a bug in the platform and should report it.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this as well. My solution: Add 'user_groups' to the list of required permissions. Log out, log in again and everything should work.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Someone please accept this answer. It was just luck that I found it, and it solves this bug.