# (Probable) inconsistency in "id"s returned by facebook Graph API and Realtime Updates?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

related to [Open Graph api for feed returning inconsistent results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9643148/369489)

When I publish a post on a page's feed using my App, facebook returns some id in the form of `<page_id>_<post_id>`, but when the same App receives a Real time Update from the same page—say a like or a comment—the `parent_id` field of the like or comment contains only the `<post_id>` part!

Is this a bug or what?

Comment: This is causing issues to me as well. I created this bug reported on facebook using your question.   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/675531292466149

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from facebook engineers -

**This is by design. For a realtime update generated by a comment, the parent_id will just show  and not include the page_id.**

**For specific examples, please refer to our documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime) and look under the sub-sections "Feed Example."**